# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier (Heroku App Deployment)

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to open my Heroku application after deploying it, but its giving me the following error:

> "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier"

To resolve the above mentioned error, I tried tailing my log file with a: `heroku logs --tail` which gave the following output:

```
2019-04-02T22:59:58.024020+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
2019-04-02T22:59:58.024021+00:00 app[web.1]: app = eval(obj, vars(mod))
2019-04-02T22:59:58.024022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<string>", line 1
2019-04-02T22:59:58.024023+00:00 app[web.1]: app
2019-04-02T22:59:58.024024+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-04-02T22:59:58.024027+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue after

removing any unnecessary space from Procfile and rewrite the following the line

web: gunicorn deployed:app